# Office 365 disregards MX record configuration after moving to Google Workspaces

Tags: domain-name-system, microsoft-office-365, g-suite, office365

We have recently moved from Office 365 to Google Workspaces. Let's say the domain name is `example.com`. We let Google switch MX records in the domain management of our provider but did not touch Office 365 settings. We started to receive all e-mails addressed to `@example.com` the Google inbox as expected.

However, when sending from Office 365 e-mail to `@example.com` it ends up in the inbox of Outlook and not in Google. It looks like Office 365 does not look at the DNS record when it thinks it owns this domain.

How can I make Office 365 send the e-mails to Google, while keeping Office 365 as an identity service? (meaning, I want users to be able to log-in to Office/Microsoft with the `@example.com` identity)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by creating a connector in Exchange Online to deliver email for your accepted domain to Google Workspace. See the images below. In addition, Office 365 support is free. If you can't get this working then open a support case from the Office 365 Admin Center. They'll help you get it configured and working.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]